# Rotation in python with ndimage

Tags: python, rotation, scipy

I need to rotate a lot of images in a folder using Python. I found out, it could be done using `ndimage.rotate`. But I get a problem, as the image is not being rotated: I wait and wait, and it takes so much time...

This is the discussed part of my code:

```
for image in filelist:
    print 'Checking ', os.path.basename(image)
    im = misc.imread(image)
    geom = im.shape
    print geom
    if geom[1] > geom[0]:
        # Some code to determine the way image should be rotated, which 
        # calculates angle
        print 'Rotating ', os.path.basename(image)
        rotated = ndimage.rotate(im, angle, reshape = False)
        print 'Rotated ', os.path.basename(image)
        misc.imsave(image, rotated)
    else:
        print os.path.basename(image), ' is OK'
```

When I run it it works really slow, about 20 sec per image. How to do it faster? I would appreciate any help with it.

And just in case, I am not a professional programmer.

Comment: Try to resize to a smaller image and see if that works. I am guessing it is just taking a long time to do the rotation. I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh, no, you are right... SO the question transforms into "How to do it fast?"

Comment: Which vesion of scipy and python are you using ?

Comment: Python 2.7.3, SciPy 0.10.1

Comment: Don't know if it will be faster, slower or just the same but have you tried PIL? http://pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm

Comment: Trying it now, thank you. I'll tell a sec later.

Comment: That's fantastic! PIL is million times faster, does it immidiately!

Comment: SciPy's `rotate` defaults to cubic spline interpolation, while PIL's defaults to nearest neighbor. If you add the keyword parameter `order=0` to SciPy, it should speed up considerably, and if you add `filter=PIL.Image.BICUBIC` (which is equivalent to `filter=3`) to PIL it will slow down. It is always a good idea to read the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html and http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm

Comment: Thank you! It might have been the reason, you are right.

Comment: Tough, using scipy with order = 0 mine still takes around 20 seconds for a 256x256x256 matrix. Maybe PIL is the way. Wait, I dont think PIL rotate works for nd images, correct me if wrong

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is to use PIL instead of ndimage as deinonychusaur suggested. You might want to look here:
pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm

It has everything needed to write a program with PIL.

Comment: i think the comment by Jaime explain the problem and solution better. docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/… and pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm